# string not accepting " 's " while writing to database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, type-conversion

Hello everyone i am creating a settings page for another application using mvc4. In the settings page:

1.It contains two text areas wherein the user can type anything.

2.After typing if the user clicks submit button, the text he has written is saved in a sql database.

3.The main application will read that data from the database and display it.

Here are my respective codes:

Model:

```
 public string PartnerInfo1 { get; set; }
 public string PartnerInfo2 { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(AddDetailModel model)
        {
            pinfo1 = model.PartnerInfo1;
            pinfo2 = model.PartnerInfo2;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sample"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update dbo.Partner_Design set PartnerInfo1='" + pinfo1 + "',PartnerInfo2='" + pinfo2 + "' where [PartnerID]='cs'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

and in the view:

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.PartnerInfo1)
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.PartnerInfo2)
```

in the database, the corresponding table contains two columns **PartnerInfo1,PartnerInfo2**  and their datatype is **nvarchar(max)**.

My problem is when i type apostrophe in text area it gives me error.For example if i type "world's" it gives error on clicking submit button.

This is the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 's'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.
```

Please suggest what i can do to avoid this.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use parameters. Don't (repeat DO NOT) build your query by string concatenation. Parameterizing your UPDATE statement will fix both your unescaped input AND ensure that no-one can inject unauthorised SQL into your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method expose your query to `sql injection` attacks. You are much better using a parameterised query which will sort out your `'` issue as well.

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sample"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update dbo.Partner_Design " +
                                    "Set PartnerInfo1=@pinfo1, " +
                                        "PartnerInfo2=@pinfo2 " +
                                    "Where [PartnerID]=@partnerId", con);

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pinfo1", model.PartnerInfo1);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pinfo2", model.PartnerInfo2);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partnerId", "cs");
   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: if i use ur approach the database is not updating.But if i use my approach it is working fine

Comment: That is wired, please have a look at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) example.

Comment: i am using exactly the same technique which is shown in the example given by you, but still it is not updating

Comment: that is the weird thing...none at all!!...the code is executing fine but when i check the database, it is not getting updated

Comment: Try now, this is even better, using `using` so it will dispose your connection at the end of using block. **Please note**, partner id is always cs in my code, you need to assign a correct parameter to it.

Answer (score 4):

Never do that - it's unsafe and allow to make [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update dbo.Partner_Design set PartnerInfo1='" + pinfo1 + "',PartnerInfo2='" + pinfo2 + "' where [PartnerID]='cs'", con);
```

Instead of that use the following parameters syntax:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update dbo.Partner_Design set PartnerInfo1=@pinfo1, PartnerInfo2=@pinfo2 where [PartnerID]='cs'", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pinfo1", pinfo1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pinfo2", pinfo2);
```

Comment: If i use ur approach , the database is not updating.But with my method it is updating fine.

Comment: @nitinvertigo: You still need to call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` to actually run the query against the database. Then it should execute just fine...

Comment: @ArjanEinbu i am calling cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() but still it is not updating

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the single quote by prefixing it with another single quote, which would require doing a replace on your string before you add it to the query i.e.:

```
pinfo1 = pinfo1.Replace("'", "''");
pinfo2 = pinfo2.Replace("'", "''");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update dbo.Partner_Design set PartnerInfo1='" + pinfo1 + "',PartnerInfo2='" + pinfo2 + "' where [PartnerID]='cs'", con);
```

I would however strongly advise against this and take the advice of the other responses that instead use parameterised SQL which is much more secure. Note also that this solution will only solve your single quotes problem, and will still cause issues with other special characters that need escaping individually. As such whilst this should answer your question, the solutions proposed by Sławomir Rosiek and Kaf are much more comprehensive, much safer, and are best practice.

The method you are using leaves you open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: thanks your code works fine. but the methods which are suggested above to prevent injection attacks does not update my DB.using my code works without problems.

Comment: I would still strongly recommend figuring out why those other methods aren't working and persevere with getting them to work, else your code is a security breach waiting to happen.

Comment: the solution provided by Kaf is working now...so i am marking his answer as correct. Your solution is fine too but i can't accept 2 answers.Sorry for that